# "Granda cantora !" Granda? Desque quando "grande" tem gênero variável?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, concordância, gênero

Já ouvi (em ptPT) alguém expressar-se dessa forma: "granda cantora!"  ou "estou com uma raiva muito granda."  Isso é gramatical em ptPT?
No Brasil é certamente errado, uma vez que "grande" não varia em gênero.

Edit - "uma granda raiva" é o que devo ter ouvido.

Comment: "Estou com uma raiva muito granda" não se diz em lado nenhum — se ouviste isso provavelmente foi porque a pessoa se enganou, ou qualquer coisa do género. "Estou com uma granda raiva" talvez se use, no entanto. Mas não tem que ver com género: também se pode dizer "estou com um granda peso na consciência", por exemplo.

Comment: Mesmo "granda raiva" é pouco idiomático. Google search: *granda raiva* 76; _granda f**a_ 2.770; *granda puta* 4.030; *granda maluco* 7.440.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não se trata de uma concordância em género. Poderia dizer-se também "*granda* cantor!" ou "*ganda* cantor". São apenas variações fonéticas que dão mais ênfase ao adjetivo.

Como o JNat aponta, esta forma ocorre quase exclusivamente em posição pré-nominal.

Comment: Então a palavra "granda" nada tem a ver com "grande" ?  Nem em origem e nem em significado?

Comment: @Centaurus Claro que tem. Como disse, é apenas uma variação de "grande".